# How can I force a consistent Partition UUID across virtualised/native boot or somehow get the new one

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, virtualbox, virtualization

Im running 1804 with win 10 in a dual boot setup. both installs are on the same physical disk, on different partitions.

Now I recently managed to get my ubuntu partition booting from the windows host as a guest, which is very nice when I just want to jump in quickly for something.

This has been done by building a vmdk which points to the physical drive and copying and modifying my efi grub config to a bootable image.

The issue I have is that my ubuntu install currently has visibility of the full disk when virtualised (even though it only really need the one partition to boot) - to prevent risk of data loss/corruption I would like to ideally build my vmdk with just access to one partition. However doing this changes the UUID of the partition and by extension screws the bootloader.

So how can I either force a particular uuid to that partition, or some how work out what the partition uuid will be so I can alter my virtualised boot loader.

On a slightly cheeky folow up - I am also interested in the best place to put some boot up checks to do conditional mounting of disks based on detected virtualisation so any related thoughts around this would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Either:

Use...

- **uuidgen** # generate new UUID's
- **tune2fs** # write UUID's to disk

or...

- change your **/etc/fstab** to use hard device codes (*like /dev/sda4*) instead of UUID's.